# What is the difference between popup, panel, and detached_panel?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am using the [Window manipulator](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/window-manipulator) web extension example to determine which browser.windows.create *type* I should use. The plugin allows you to quickly create popup, panel, and detached_panel windows.

Here's a snippet from the example:

```js
let createData = {
      type: "panel",
    };
    let creating = browser.windows.create(createData);
    creating.then(() => {
      console.log("The panel has been created");
    });
```

The problem is that I can't tell the difference between these three types of windows. They all look the same to me.

[The documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/CreateType) at MDN mentions the names of the types but does not seem to explain the differences between them.

Is there something about my setup that is making it so I cannot tell the difference between these types of windows or is it just not readily apparent to the end user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox only differentiates two types "normal" (or not specified) and everything else. So popup, panel, and detached_panel are basically interchangeable.

https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/a777ff11b6d700a698c61e5bd17e73b044304494/browser/components/extensions/parent/ext-windows.js#301-313